# Search Credit Cards in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to find plain credit card number in my database.

I want to make sure that a text content does not contain credit cards. As some client type their credit cards when they file report
I tried :

```
SELECT * FROM reports WHERE content RLIKE '\b(?:\d[ -]*?){13,16}\b';
```

It gave me this error

> ERROR 1139 (42000): Got error 'repetition-operator operand invalid' from regexp

I need some help please.
Thanks

Comment: MySQL regular expressions don't have escape sequences like `\b`. Have you read the MySQL [regexp documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/regexp.html)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL regular expression syntax doesn't use `\b` for word boundaries, it uses`[[:<:]]` and `[[:>:]]`. It doesn't use `\d` for digits, it uses `[[:digit:]]`. It also doesn't have `?:` prefix in groups -- they're not needed because it doesn't have back-references, so there's no difference between capturing and non-capturing groups.

But the reason for your error message is that it doesn't have non-greedy quantifiers like `*?`.

Try this:

```
SELECT *
FROM reports
WHERE content RLIKE '[[:<:]]([[:digit:]][- ]?){13,16}[[:>:]]'
```

This matches a word beginning, 13-16 digits with a possible separator after each, followed by a word end.